# jQuery infinite recursion when tring to call a plugin on elements added on the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, bootstrap-switch

**EDIT**: http://jsfiddle.net/J26Dw/ (click Add)

I want to call, for every checkbox marked with the attribute `data-widget="bootstrap-switch"`, the `bootstrapSwitch()` plugin. This works fine with this simple function:

```
$(function () {
    var activator = 'data-widget="bootstrap-switch"';

    $('input[type="checkbox"][' + activator + ']')
        .each(function () {
            $(this).bootstrapSwitch();
        });
});
```

What if the checkbox was created/added on the fly to the DOM, i.e. clicking a button ?

I tried to catch the `DOMNodeInserted` event and then call `bootstrapSwitch()` on the added element, only if the `.data('bootstrap-switch')` is `undefined`. I get the following console error (along with a great number of checkboxes :P):

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '[' + activator + ']', function(e) {
    var el = $(e.target);

    console.log(el.attr('data-widget')); // Returns "bootstrap-switch", OK

    if (!el.data('bootstrap-switch')) {
        el.bootstrapSwitch(); // Infinite recursion
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`bootstrapSwitch` has to be causing the recursion loop. It obviously rebuilds the checkbox. In doing so, it must do something to retrigger the `DomNodeInserted` callback, like remove the target element and re-append it to the document.

In any event, I think this accomplishes what you're trying to do:

```
$(function () {
    var options   = {},
        selector  = 'input[type="checkbox"][data-widget="bootstrap-switch"]',
        activator = function () { $(this).bootstrapSwitch(options); };

    $(selector).each(activator);

    $('#btn-add').click(function () {
        var $newInput = $('<input>', {
           "type": 'checkbox',
           "data-widget": 'bootstrap-switch'
        });
        $('.holder').append($newInput);
        activator.apply($newInput);
    });

    $('#btn-copy').click(function () {
        var $clonedInput = $('#switch').clone();
        $('.holder').append($clonedInput);
        activator.apply($clonedInput);
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/LAUx9/

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but the `#btn-add` and `#btn-copy` were just example: checkboxes can be added in other ways to the DOM (i.e. I have no control over it). Is there a solution in this case?

Comment: @gremo Yes, by applying the same pattern demonstrated here. If there is some reason why that pattern would not work, well, that would have to be articulated, perhaps in a new more carefully worded question.